# Issue with Microsoft Webview2 Shared UserDataFolder c#

Tags: c#, webview2

There is WinForms Application in which Webview2 Browser are used in multiple places.
For WebView2 browser there is a wrapper class created something like below.

```
public class WebViewWrapper : UserControl
{
    private WebView2 webBrowser;
    private static bool m_supportSSO = false;    
    public WebView2Wrapper()
    {            
        InitializeComponent();
        initWebView();
    }
    
    private void initWebView()
    {
        webBrowser.NavigationCompleted += webBrowser_NavigationCompleted;
        webBrowser.CoreWebView2InitializationCompleted += webBrowser_CoreWebView2InitializationCompleted;

        var options = new CoreWebView2EnvironmentOptions("--autoplay-policy=no-user-gesture-required --ignore-certificate-errors");

        if (m_supportSSO)
            options.AllowSingleSignOnUsingOSPrimaryAccount = true;

        //user data folder must be process specific in order to prevent nasty crashes
        System.Diagnostics.Process proc = System.Diagnostics.Process.GetCurrentProcess();
        string proc_name = proc.ProcessName;
        var userDataFolder = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData) + "\\Test\\" + proc_name;
        if (proc_name.StartsWith("EditorApp", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
        {
            userDataFolder += ("_" + proc.Id);
        }
        m_env = CoreWebView2Environment.CreateAsync(null, userDataFolder, options).Result;
    }
    public async void InitCoreWebView2Async()
    {
      try
      {

        logger.CreateMessage().Info("Initialise CoreWebView2");
        await webBrowser.EnsureCoreWebView2Async(m_env);

      }
      catch (Exception ex)
      {
        logger.CreateMessage().Error("Exception while navigating to {0}", ex);
      }
    }
                    
    private void InitializeComponent()
    {
        this.webBrowser = new Microsoft.Web.WebView2.WinForms.WebView2();
        ((System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize)(this.webBrowser)).BeginInit();
        this.SuspendLayout();

        // webBrowser
        //
        this.webBrowser.BackColor = Color.Black;
        this.webBrowser.CreationProperties = null;
        this.webBrowser.DefaultBackgroundColor = Color.Black;
        this.webBrowser.Dock = System.Windows.Forms.DockStyle.Fill;
        this.webBrowser.ForeColor = Color.Black;
        this.webBrowser.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(0, 0);
        this.webBrowser.Name = "webBrowser";
        this.webBrowser.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(249, 167);
        this.webBrowser.TabIndex = 0;
        this.webBrowser.TabStop = false;
        this.webBrowser.ZoomFactor = 1D;
        //
        // WebViewWrapper
        //
        this.BackColor = Color.Black;
        this.Controls.Add(this.webBrowser);
        this.ForeColor = Color.Black;
        this.Name = "WebViewWrapper";
        this.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(249, 167);
        ((System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize)(this.webBrowser)).EndInit();
        this.ResumeLayout(false);
        this.PerformLayout();

    }       
    public void SetSource(Uri uri)
    {
      if (webBrowser != null)
      {
        webBrowser.Source = uri;
      }
    }
    
}
```

Browser Class where its not working

```
 public partial class BrowserClass
  {
    public BrowserClass()
    {
      InitializeComponent();
      webBrowser.InitCoreWebView2Async();     
    }
  }
private void InitializeComponent()
    {
      this.webBrowser = new WebViewWrapper();
      this.SuspendLayout();
      // webBrowser
      this.webBrowser.Dock = System.Windows.Forms.DockStyle.Fill;
      this.webBrowser.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(0, 0);
      this.webBrowser.MinimumSize = new System.Drawing.Size(20, 20);
      this.webBrowser.Name = "webBrowser";
      this.webBrowser.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(150, 150);
      this.webBrowser.TabIndex = 0;
      // BrowserControlInstance
      this.AutoScaleDimensions = new System.Drawing.SizeF(6F, 13F);
      this.AutoScaleMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoScaleMode.Font;
      this.Controls.Add(this.webBrowser);
      this.Name = "BrowserControlInstance";
      this.ResumeLayout(false);

    }


    public WebViewWrapper webBrowser
```

Invoking Place Code

```
  BrowserClass wb = new BrowserClass()
  wb.webBrowser.SetSource(new Uri(url));
```

In my application all the places WebViewWrapper is working fine(corewebview2 initialization, navigating to html) except in one place.
Getting exception when EnsureCoreWebView2Async is called and corewebview2 is not initialized

```
InitCoreWebView2Async -> 
System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException (0x8007139F): The group or resource is not in the correct state to perform the requested operation. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007139F)
 at System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ThrowExceptionForHRInternal(Int32 errorCode, IntPtr errorInfo)
 at Microsoft.Web.WebView2.Core.CoreWebView2Environment.<CreateCoreWebView2ControllerAsync>d__54.MoveNext()
End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
 at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
 at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
 at Microsoft.Web.WebView2.WinForms.WebView2.<InitCoreWebView2Async>d__18.MoveNext()
 End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
 at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
 at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
 at Basic.Wrappers.WebViewWrapper.<InitCoreWebView2Async>d__35.MoveNext()
```

https://github.com/MicrosoftEdge/WebView2Feedback/issues/2323
From this link found that UserData folder can be shared as long as Options used to create CoreWebView2EnvironmentOptions are same across all instance of webview2.

instead of sharing user data folder path if new folder path is used to  create then there is no issue all webview2 controls are working fine.

What I'm not understanding is why its not working even though I'm using common code to create a webview2 instance where options and user data folder path are set same across all webview2 instance.

Appreciate  the help